# Javascript: What should max be initialized to?

Tags: javascript

What should max be initialized to? I've been trying to work it out, but have had no luck.

```
NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 5;

var i;
var max;
var userInput; // Input from user

max = ???? ;
for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; i++)
{ userInput = parseInt(prompt('Enter input: '));
if (userInput > max)
max = userInput;
}

alert('Max: ' + max);
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Also, you aren't handling the case where the user hits cancel to the prompt.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for a definitive answer. `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` as in the accepted answer is one logical interpretation, but depending on what the code is for `0` or some positive number might be more appropriate as a default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Javascript [`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/negative_infinity) constant.  That way any user input will be bigger than what the variable is initialized to since `NEGATIVE_INIFINTY` is smaller than all other numbers that JS can represent.

Comment: What makes `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` a better choice than `-Infinity`?

Comment: Nothing @Matt, they represent the same concept.  Don't know why I got the tick as you have a more complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

How about [`-Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)? Or, you can use `null`, and special-case it:

```
if (max == null || userInput > max) {
    max = userInput;
}
```

If you want to get really fancy, don't write the loop yourself at all. Let [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) do the work:

```
var i;
var userInputs = [];
var max;

for (i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; i++)
{
    userInputs.push(parseInt(prompt('Enter input: '), 10));
                                                 // ↑↑↑↑ always pass the radix
                                                 // to parseInt()
}

max = Math.max.apply(null, userInputs);
```

Comment: Clever use of `Math.max` -- though it is a little confusing and I would just go for comparisons to `-Infinity` (since sometimes algorithms like this warrant complexity that rules out `Math.max` anyway).

Answer (score 1):

[`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY) is probably a good choice but actually, you don't *have* to initialise it to anything, there are a couple of other options. You can "de-loop" the first iteration so that it forces the assignment to `max`:

```
NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 5;
var i;
var max;
var userInput;

userInput = parseInt (prompt ('Enter input: '));
max = userInput;
for (i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; i++) {
    userInput = parseInt (prompt ('Enter input: '));
    if (userInput > max)
        max = userInput;
}
alert('Max: ' + max);
```

although that results in a little bit of code duplication and it just *looks* unclean.

Alternatively, you can use the `i` control variable to force it on the first iteration of the loop:

```
NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 5;
var i;
var max;
var userInput;

for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; i++) {
    userInput = parseInt (prompt ('Enter input: '));
    if ((i == 0) || (userInput > max))
        max = userInput;
}
alert('Max: ' + max);
```